# Spectral Representation: sign of coefficients.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I am reading about Spectral Analysis from [this](http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~stine/stat910/lectures/17_spectral_rep.pdf) set of notes, and I have some doubts regarding the algebraic manipulation. Since I am kinda new in this topic I don't really know if I'm missing something or there's a typo.

They start defining $X_t=\sum_jA_j\cos(2\pi\lambda_jt)+B_j\sin(2\pi\lambda_jt)$ (**where X is a real-values random variable**), and then they re-express it using the complex representation: $\sum_{\pm j}Ce^{2\pi i\lambda_jt}$ where $C_{-j}=C^*_j$ (since $X$ is real valued) and $\lambda_{-j}=-\lambda_j$

Then they give the following definition $C_j=A_j+iB_j$

Taking one term of the summation we can re express it as:

$$(A_j+iB_j)[\cos(2\pi\lambda_jt)+i\sin(2\pi\lambda_jt)]+(A_j-iB_j)[\cos(-2\pi\lambda_jt)+i\sin(-2\pi\lambda_jt)]=$$
$$\cos(2\pi\lambda_jt)[A_j+iB_j+A_j-iB_j]+i\sin(2\pi\lambda_jt)[A_j+iB_j-A_j+iB_j]=$$
$$2A_jcos(2\pi\lambda_jt)-2B_j\sin(2\pi\lambda_jt)$$

But it's easy to see that actually the coefficients are different (multiplied by $2$) and we have a minus instead of a plus.

My question is, did the authors considered $C_j=A_j+iB_j$ as a way to say that $C_j$ is  a complex number, or were they making reference to the coefficients of the first expression?
The notation is somehow ambiguous.

Comment: $(A_j+iB_j)[…]+(A_j-iB_j)[…]=2A_j[…]$.

Comment: You are right, there's a typo there, I missed a minus sign. Thanks

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts done, now I think it's ok